# How to convert this statement from MySQL to HQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

This is the SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT opc.contenido, COUNT(r.idOpcPregunta)  
from  Opcionesrespuestas as opc LEFT JOIN Respuestasimples as r ON r.idOpcPregunta = opc.idOpcPregunta 
where opc.idPregunta ='6' 
GROUP BY opc.idOpcPregunta;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the sentence HQL**

```
select opc.contenido, count(r.idOpcPregunta)   from  Respuestasimples as r
right join r.idOpcPregunta as opc  where opc.idPregunta ='6'  
group by opc.contenido
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a HQL

```
select opc.contenido, count(r.idOpcPregunta)  
from  Opcionesrespuestas as opc 
left join opc.OpcPregunta as r  
where opc.idPregunta ='6' 
group by opc.contenido;
```

Comment: I've solved thanks `select opc.contenido, count(r.idOpcPregunta)  
from  Respuestasimple as r 
right join r.idOpcPregunta as opc  where opc.idPregunta ='6' 
group by opc.contenido`